# Finding a route using Best First Search

Tags: prolog

I have to do some work in Prolog which I am not very familiar with. I need to find path from one station to another station for London Underground with travel time in minutes. I need to apply "best first search" to achieve the goal. I need a head start for this as I have never done work before in Prolog. I have started a bit but have no idea how to go further. Any help will be appreciated. Here is my starter:

```
adjacent(waterloo,westminster,jubilee,2).
adjacent(westminster,green_park,jubilee,2).
adjacent(green_park,bond_street,jubilee,2).
adjacent(bond_street,baker_street,jubilee,2).

adjacent(waterloo,embankment,northern,2).
adjacent(embankment,charing_cross,northern,1).
adjacent(charing_cross,leicester_square,northern,1).
adjacent(leicester_square,tottenham_court_road,northern,2).
adjacent(tottenham_court_road,goodge_street,northern,1).
adjacent(goodge_street,warren_street,northern,2).
adjacent(warren_street,euston,northern,1).

adjacent(waterloo,embankment,bakerloo,2).
adjacent(embankment,charing_cross,bakerloo,1).
adjacent(charing_cross,piccadilly_circus,bakerloo,2).
adjacent(piccadilly_circus,oxford_circus,bakerloo,2).
adjacent(oxford_circus,regents_park,bakerloo,2).
adjacent(regents_park,baker_street,bakerloo,2).

go(Start, Goal) :-
empty_set(Closed_set),
empty_pq(Open),
heuristic(Start, Goal, H),
insert_pq([Start, nil, 0, H, H], Open, Open_pq),
path(Open_pq, Closed_set, Goal).

path(Open_pq, _, _) :-
empty_pq(Open_pq),
write('Graph searched; no solution found.').

path(Open_pq, Closed_set, Goal) :-
dequeue_pq([State, Parent, _, _, _], Open_pq, _),
my_equal(State,Goal),
write('The solution path is'), nl,
printsolution([State, Parent, _, _, _], Closed_set).

path(Open_pq, Closed_set, Goal) :-
dequeue_pq([State, Parent, D, H, S], Open_pq, Rest_open_pq),
get_children([State, Parent, D, H, S], Rest_open_pq, Closed_set, Children, Goal),
insert_list_pq(Children, Rest_open_pq, New_open_pq),
my_union([[State, Parent, D, H, S]], Closed_set, New_closed_set),
path(New_open_pq, New_closed_set, Goal),!.

get_children([State, _, D, _, _], Rest_open_pq, Closed_set, Children, Goal) :-
(bagof(Child,
moves([State, _, D, _, _], Rest_open_pq,Closed_set, Child, Goal),
Children);
Children = []).

moves([State, _, Depth, _, _], Rest_open_pq, Closed_set,
[Next, State, New_D, H, S], Goal) :-
move(State, Next),
not(member_pq([Next, _, _, _, _], Rest_open_pq)),
not(member_set2([Next, _, _, _, _], Closed_set, _)),
New_D is Depth + 1,
heuristic(Next, Goal, H),
S is New_D + H.

printsolution([[X, Y, _, _], nil, _, _, _], _) :-
write([X, Y]), nl.

printsolution([State, Parent, _, _, _], Closed_set) :-
member_set2([Parent, _, _, _, _], Closed_set, Grandparent),
printsolution([Parent, Grandparent, _, _, _], Closed_set),
my_write(State).

my_write([X, Y, _, _]) :-
write([X, Y]),nl.

my_equal([X, Y, _, _], [Z, W]) :-
X = Z,
Y = W.
```

Comment: You have posted the graph instanance but also post some code showing what you did. Do you really want [best-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best-first_search) or as shown in the tags [breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)? Maybe [Dijkstra's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) will do?

Comment: I want best first search actually. I have tried a lot of things already but here is the code where I am right now but don't know how to go further.

Comment: I have updated the code. Please have a look. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Iterative deepening lets you do best-first in a way that doesn't get into loops.
https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=call_with_depth_limit/3

Comment: So it is built-in?

Comment: @HamzaZaheer Not really. the above limits the depth of the proof search, which can be made to be the (a factor of) the current path length by which you looking-through-the-graph. But it may just as easy to roll one's own depth-limited search (I think). That's a predicate of some interest though ... also a sign that there is much space in Prolog to control the search which goes untapped now.

Comment: As I mentioned this is my first time working with prolog, so I don't really understand what you're trying to say. Would it be possible for you share some code for best first search that may be applicable to my problem? As that might help me understand better.

Comment: Please don't link off to external sites like this unless the link is supporting content you already have in your answer. In other words, your content should stand alone in being necessary and sufficient to answer the question. Would "Iterative deepening lets you do best-first in a way that doesn't get into loops" suffice alone?

Comment: I don't feel like doing someone's homework for them - a quick websearch for iterative deepening and the specific call_with_depth_limit/3 should be more than enough of a hint.